# Python lists / Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
   Streets= [{"index": 1, "name": "east 13th", "location": ["pizza store", "shoe store"]}, 
    {"index": 2, "name": "east 14th", "location": ["pizza store", "flower store"]},
    {"index": 3, "name": "east 15th", "location": ["shoe store", "massage parlor"]},
    {"index": 4, "name": "east 16th", "location": "shoe store"}]
```

How would I print something that is at the location on east 14th street? I tried `print Streets.values()` but that doesn't seem to work - it works when there is only one array in the list, not four arrays (seemingly).

Also, I want to map needs to locations. So when for instance the user 'goes' into a shoe store on 'east 15th' street, another list of:

Needs = {hunger, thirst, clothing, shelter}

is reduced by 'clothing'. And, if a person tries to go into a shoe store again when they don't have the 'clothing' need, the program will return an output of something like

"You looked at the items and realized you didn't need anything they could provide."

Not typing it in terms of code here, I would write it something along the lines of:

```
    If the user tries to enter into the location
       Check what needs are mapped to that location
       If the needs which are mapped to that location are currently unmet
          The user enters in to that location and interacts with the 'shop keep'
       If the needs which are mapped to that location are currently met
          The user enters in to that location, looks around, and leaves.

   Go back to default state
```

So how would I map the 'hunger' need to both the 'pizza store' which is located at 'east 13th' and the 'pizza store' which is located at 'east 14th'?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Hint: `[d["location"] for d in Streets if d["name"] == "east 14th"]` would be a place to start. Look up list and dictionary comprehensions and learn how to use them. Once you understand that construct, the rest of your concepts should be a bit easier to resolve...

Answer (score 0):

You have a list with dictionaries. You can loop the the list and in each list search for a needed key and value

```
 for d in Streets:
        if d["name"] == "east 14th":
            print(d["location"])
```

OUTPUT

['pizza store', 'flower store']